# Не работает плавно slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, такая ситуация, `slideToggle` не делает плавное открытие элементов, просто "вставляет" скрытый элемент. Отчасти помогла `hide()` и `show()`.

`show()` - начинает плавно открывать но в конце делает рывок

`hide()` - плавно не закрывает тоже

Живой пример [тут](https://vk.cc/7NsvuR)

Проблему можно посмотреть если по нажимать на кнопку "Посмотреть все торты". Чуть ниже есть "Посмотреть все начинки", работает нормально, хочу добиться такого же эффекта.

Comment: Перенесите хотя бы как-то свой код в здешний виджет, что бы можно было поиграться. На первый взгляд причина может быть в том, что у вас `.hidden_blocks_tort.hidden7` не имеет высоты, так как блоки `float: left`, и нет `clear:both`

Comment: Ладно, поигрался чутка "на живую", в общем добавьте `.hidden_blocks_tort.hidden7 { clear:both; } .hidden_blocks_tort.hidden7::after { content: ''; display: table; clear:both; }` и все будет нормально.

Comment: MedvedevDev, спасибо, помогло решить проблему. Если ответишь не комментарием приму как правильный ответ твой.

Comment: Чтобы написать ответ - нужно сначала в вопрос добавить MVCE. Иначе через пару месяцев на сайте будет другой код - и незачем такой вопрос держать вообще в базе знаний.